# ¿Cómo utilizar onTextChanged con un EditText?

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio

Buen día comunidad, vuelvo a plantear la pregunta, resultó que no me exprese bien anteriormente. Lo que trato de implementar es una barra de búsqueda en mi interfaz, pero no mediante el uso de un "SerachView", lo trato de realizar con un "EditText" utilizando "TextWatcher" con el método del TextWatcher: "onTextChanged"
La información que quiero que se filtre la obtengo de mi base de datos y se muestra en un "listView", pero no he podido implementarla correctamente.

**Método para obtener la información de la base de datos**

```
public void consultar(){
    usuarios = new ArrayList<String>();
    JsonArrayRequest jAR = new JsonArrayRequest("URL", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    usuarios.add(jsonObject.getString("usuarios"));
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(registrosUsuarios.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, usuarios);
                    lVUsuarios.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    );
    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    rQueue.add(jAR);
}
```

Como pueden ver creo un "ArrayAdapter" al cual le asigno el ArrayList: "usuarios" y paso ese parametro al "ListView" para imprimirlo.
Lo que busco es que utilizando ese "ArrayAdpater" en conjunto con el "TextWatcher" haga que mí "EditText" filtre la información.

**TextWatcher**

```
eTSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Y no puedo acceder a ese "ArrayAdapter", porque solamente se puede utilizar para ese método, ¿Se puede crear un "ArrayAdapter" de manera global? O que es lo que me recomiendan hacer.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN (PROBLEMA RESUELTO)**

Si se puede crear un "ArrayAdapter" de manera global, pero olvide lo más básico de Java y por eso no obtenía el resultado. Pero el código ya funciona como buscaba.

> Creación del ArrayAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(registrosUsuarios.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, usuarios);
```

> Método para obtener la información de la base de datos

```
  public void consultar(){
        usuarios = new ArrayList<String>();
        JsonArrayRequest jAR = new JsonArrayRequest("URL", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        usuarios.add(jsonObject.getString("usuarios"));
                        lVUsuarios.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        );
        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        rQueue.add(jAR);
    }
```

> TextWatcher

```
eTSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Acomoda ese código por favor. No sé entiende si tienes funciones anidadas (que no existen en Java).

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente mediante `onTextChanged`? ¿En qué parte de tu código lo estás implementando? Pulsa en [edit] para clarificar tu problema.

Comment: Editada la pregunta

Comment: El onTextChanged lo quiero para que filtre la información que obtengo mediante una consulta a mi base de datos. Y lo trato de implementar en: "onCreate"